# WPF Datagrid DataBinding DataView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

**Pre-Warning** sorry WPF new guy here:

I have a DataGrid bound to a DataTable's DefaultView

```
ResultDataGrid.ItemsSource = resultTable.DefaultView;
```

I know the column names, and I need to change a column's foreground if another column is `1` (always 0 or 1)

Currently what I have:

```
private void ResultDataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "columnName")
        {
            e.Column.CellStyle = FindResource("columnStyle") as Style;
        }
}
```

and in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" x:Key="columnStyle">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding resultTable, Path={StaticResource otherColumnName}}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Where otherColumnName is set in the constructor

```
public ResultsCustom(DataTable resultclass, CustomQuery query)
{
    // Some other stuff
    this.Resources.Add("otherColumnName", COLUMN_NAME);
}
```

The XAML Style seems to not have the correct path, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about this line of code:

```
Path={StaticResource otherColumnName}
```

Are you attempting to compare the property "otherColumnName" of the resultTable to see if this is 1?  This wouldn't be a static resource, and you could change your binding to:

```
Path=otherColumnName
```

Comment: this fixed it, but I am trying to use "otherColumnName" as a variable, I thought that adding it as a resource would allow for that